# Is there a way to speed up the Element.scrollIntoView 'smooth' behavior? What is 'auto'?

Tags: javascript

I have a couple questions about the experimental scrollIntoViewOptions of the `Element.scrollIntoView` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). I know it's experimental, but I'm on Chrome 65, so I figured I might as well use it.

1. What does it mean for `behavior` to be set to `auto`. On my machine, `auto` seems to perform identically to `instant`
2. When I set `behavior` to `smooth`, and want to scroll to something in a table, it scrolls only very sloooooowly to the element I want. Does anyone have any general pointers for how to speed up this type of animation (if possible)? I don't necessarily need you to do everything for me, I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if your question is still relevant but since I was testing it, I thought I could share the status of this [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function as of today.

**Answers to your questions:**

1. With Chrome 71, when the `behavior` is set to `auto`, the browser scrolls immediately to the element, but with the value `smooth`, it scrolls to the element with a nice animation.
2. According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) and [specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#concept-smooth-scroll), it is not possible to control the speed of the animation:

> When a user agent is to perform a smooth scroll of a scrolling box box to position, it must update the scroll position of box in a user-agent-defined fashion **over a user-agent-defined amount of time**.

**Example of smooth behavior:**

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  box.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "center",
    inline: "nearest"
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background: red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Scroll to box</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse auctor maximus dui ac molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum scelerisque, augue non interdum egestas, felis eros pharetra ante, quis bibendum nunc odio sed turpis. Proin placerat, arcu vitae ullamcorper hendrerit, magna tortor fringilla justo, at rhoncus libero dolor id tortor. Curabitur quis leo a nisl volutpat sollicitudin sed non velit. Cras est justo, pretium in ex ac, congue tempor mi. Donec est orci, ultrices id ornare at, interdum nec eros. Quisque consectetur, nisl a condimentum efficitur, est nulla accumsan massa, aliquet interdum diam est condimentum nunc. Cras tincidunt purus a nunc porttitor imperdiet. Sed porta nulla at orci sodales, eget posuere nisi auctor. Aenean eu libero varius, condimentum diam sed, suscipit diam. Phasellus venenatis nec ligula non rutrum. Aliquam sit amet dapibus neque. Duis hendrerit malesuada ex eget semper. Quisque malesuada et libero ac mollis.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras a nisi mattis, sollicitudin risus non, pharetra mauris. Morbi eget consectetur neque, eget ornare orci. Cras mi enim, tempor condimentum urna condimentum, maximus semper nisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum gravida nisl non sapien facilisis vestibulum. Morbi luctus vestibulum consectetur. Donec rutrum molestie justo, ut posuere lectus. Vivamus facilisis, elit eget faucibus pharetra, orci dui aliquam neque, eget finibus mauris ante eu odio. Cras blandit urna dolor, ut dictum augue dignissim at. In quis mauris sed lacus venenatis hendrerit gravida id purus. Proin tristique augue id arcu finibus, a cursus neque gravida. Fusce volutpat convallis neque, at laoreet tortor placerat dignissim. Quisque hendrerit maximus arcu, quis vestibulum dui.</p>
<p>Nunc lobortis nibh vel porttitor feugiat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean orci ipsum, auctor elementum tellus at, tincidunt sollicitudin ante. Morbi justo massa, rutrum eu nulla quis, egestas bibendum quam. Aenean pretium, tellus ut porttitor convallis, turpis ligula aliquet lacus, sit amet semper dolor quam nec dui. Quisque quis ornare leo, quis tempor nunc. Nam bibendum in lectus eget pharetra. Vivamus gravida consequat lacinia. Maecenas in magna mollis, consectetur ligula ut, viverra enim. Donec sollicitudin nibh in eros gravida venenatis. Curabitur vehicula ipsum in nulla porttitor molestie. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
<p>In ullamcorper consequat massa, vitae aliquet metus tempus ac. Mauris maximus, sem et lacinia malesuada, lorem dolor molestie sapien, a molestie dolor magna ac lacus. Ut a nibh in tortor condimentum ornare nec at sem. Maecenas iaculis ac ante sit amet efficitur. Ut gravida efficitur accumsan. Donec non metus ut arcu tincidunt blandit nec et urna. Etiam mauris orci, consequat quis ipsum vel, laoreet laoreet orci. Sed felis tortor, elementum id luctus tincidunt, pretium vitae lectus. Ut tincidunt ullamcorper tortor, nec blandit risus eleifend ut. Suspendisse fringilla metus elementum ligula aliquet fermentum non gravida lectus. Vivamus mattis ullamcorper massa ut tristique. Quisque feugiat tristique dictum. Nunc vitae libero massa. Sed sagittis congue euismod.</p>
<p>In sed massa at est malesuada maximus non vel mi. Fusce tincidunt mauris eget metus fringilla venenatis. Ut dapibus nibh diam, ut efficitur risus molestie eu. Duis et tincidunt nunc, feugiat rhoncus augue. Cras dolor nibh, eleifend et purus sed, fringilla sagittis neque. Nam porta vulputate consequat. Nunc orci quam, rutrum nec dolor et, ultrices pellentesque lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse auctor maximus dui ac molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum scelerisque, augue non interdum egestas, felis eros pharetra ante, quis bibendum nunc odio sed turpis. Proin placerat, arcu vitae ullamcorper hendrerit, magna tortor fringilla justo, at rhoncus libero dolor id tortor. Curabitur quis leo a nisl volutpat sollicitudin sed non velit. Cras est justo, pretium in ex ac, congue tempor mi. Donec est orci, ultrices id ornare at, interdum nec eros. Quisque consectetur, nisl a condimentum efficitur, est nulla accumsan massa, aliquet interdum diam est condimentum nunc. Cras tincidunt purus a nunc porttitor imperdiet. Sed porta nulla at orci sodales, eget posuere nisi auctor. Aenean eu libero varius, condimentum diam sed, suscipit diam. Phasellus venenatis nec ligula non rutrum. Aliquam sit amet dapibus neque. Duis hendrerit malesuada ex eget semper. Quisque malesuada et libero ac mollis.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras a nisi mattis, sollicitudin risus non, pharetra mauris. Morbi eget consectetur neque, eget ornare orci. Cras mi enim, tempor condimentum urna condimentum, maximus semper nisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum gravida nisl non sapien facilisis vestibulum. Morbi luctus vestibulum consectetur. Donec rutrum molestie justo, ut posuere lectus. Vivamus facilisis, elit eget faucibus pharetra, orci dui aliquam neque, eget finibus mauris ante eu odio. Cras blandit urna dolor, ut dictum augue dignissim at. In quis mauris sed lacus venenatis hendrerit gravida id purus. Proin tristique augue id arcu finibus, a cursus neque gravida. Fusce volutpat convallis neque, at laoreet tortor placerat dignissim. Quisque hendrerit maximus arcu, quis vestibulum dui.</p>
<p>Nunc lobortis nibh vel porttitor feugiat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean orci ipsum, auctor elementum tellus at, tincidunt sollicitudin ante. Morbi justo massa, rutrum eu nulla quis, egestas bibendum quam. Aenean pretium, tellus ut porttitor convallis, turpis ligula aliquet lacus, sit amet semper dolor quam nec dui. Quisque quis ornare leo, quis tempor nunc. Nam bibendum in lectus eget pharetra. Vivamus gravida consequat lacinia. Maecenas in magna mollis, consectetur ligula ut, viverra enim. Donec sollicitudin nibh in eros gravida venenatis. Curabitur vehicula ipsum in nulla porttitor molestie. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
<p>In ullamcorper consequat massa, vitae aliquet metus tempus ac. Mauris maximus, sem et lacinia malesuada, lorem dolor molestie sapien, a molestie dolor magna ac lacus. Ut a nibh in tortor condimentum ornare nec at sem. Maecenas iaculis ac ante sit amet efficitur. Ut gravida efficitur accumsan. Donec non metus ut arcu tincidunt blandit nec et urna. Etiam mauris orci, consequat quis ipsum vel, laoreet laoreet orci. Sed felis tortor, elementum id luctus tincidunt, pretium vitae lectus. Ut tincidunt ullamcorper tortor, nec blandit risus eleifend ut. Suspendisse fringilla metus elementum ligula aliquet fermentum non gravida lectus. Vivamus mattis ullamcorper massa ut tristique. Quisque feugiat tristique dictum. Nunc vitae libero massa. Sed sagittis congue euismod.</p>
<p>In sed massa at est malesuada maximus non vel mi. Fusce tincidunt mauris eget metus fringilla venenatis. Ut dapibus nibh diam, ut efficitur risus molestie eu. Duis et tincidunt nunc, feugiat rhoncus augue. Cras dolor nibh, eleifend et purus sed, fringilla sagittis neque. Nam porta vulputate consequat. Nunc orci quam, rutrum nec dolor et, ultrices pellentesque lorem.</p>

<div id="box">Box</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse auctor maximus dui ac molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum scelerisque, augue non interdum egestas, felis eros pharetra ante, quis bibendum nunc odio sed turpis. Proin placerat, arcu vitae ullamcorper hendrerit, magna tortor fringilla justo, at rhoncus libero dolor id tortor. Curabitur quis leo a nisl volutpat sollicitudin sed non velit. Cras est justo, pretium in ex ac, congue tempor mi. Donec est orci, ultrices id ornare at, interdum nec eros. Quisque consectetur, nisl a condimentum efficitur, est nulla accumsan massa, aliquet interdum diam est condimentum nunc. Cras tincidunt purus a nunc porttitor imperdiet. Sed porta nulla at orci sodales, eget posuere nisi auctor. Aenean eu libero varius, condimentum diam sed, suscipit diam. Phasellus venenatis nec ligula non rutrum. Aliquam sit amet dapibus neque. Duis hendrerit malesuada ex eget semper. Quisque malesuada et libero ac mollis.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras a nisi mattis, sollicitudin risus non, pharetra mauris. Morbi eget consectetur neque, eget ornare orci. Cras mi enim, tempor condimentum urna condimentum, maximus semper nisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum gravida nisl non sapien facilisis vestibulum. Morbi luctus vestibulum consectetur. Donec rutrum molestie justo, ut posuere lectus. Vivamus facilisis, elit eget faucibus pharetra, orci dui aliquam neque, eget finibus mauris ante eu odio. Cras blandit urna dolor, ut dictum augue dignissim at. In quis mauris sed lacus venenatis hendrerit gravida id purus. Proin tristique augue id arcu finibus, a cursus neque gravida. Fusce volutpat convallis neque, at laoreet tortor placerat dignissim. Quisque hendrerit maximus arcu, quis vestibulum dui.</p>
<p>Nunc lobortis nibh vel porttitor feugiat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean orci ipsum, auctor elementum tellus at, tincidunt sollicitudin ante. Morbi justo massa, rutrum eu nulla quis, egestas bibendum quam. Aenean pretium, tellus ut porttitor convallis, turpis ligula aliquet lacus, sit amet semper dolor quam nec dui. Quisque quis ornare leo, quis tempor nunc. Nam bibendum in lectus eget pharetra. Vivamus gravida consequat lacinia. Maecenas in magna mollis, consectetur ligula ut, viverra enim. Donec sollicitudin nibh in eros gravida venenatis. Curabitur vehicula ipsum in nulla porttitor molestie. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
<p>In ullamcorper consequat massa, vitae aliquet metus tempus ac. Mauris maximus, sem et lacinia malesuada, lorem dolor molestie sapien, a molestie dolor magna ac lacus. Ut a nibh in tortor condimentum ornare nec at sem. Maecenas iaculis ac ante sit amet efficitur. Ut gravida efficitur accumsan. Donec non metus ut arcu tincidunt blandit nec et urna. Etiam mauris orci, consequat quis ipsum vel, laoreet laoreet orci. Sed felis tortor, elementum id luctus tincidunt, pretium vitae lectus. Ut tincidunt ullamcorper tortor, nec blandit risus eleifend ut. Suspendisse fringilla metus elementum ligula aliquet fermentum non gravida lectus. Vivamus mattis ullamcorper massa ut tristique. Quisque feugiat tristique dictum. Nunc vitae libero massa. Sed sagittis congue euismod.</p>
<p>In sed massa at est malesuada maximus non vel mi. Fusce tincidunt mauris eget metus fringilla venenatis. Ut dapibus nibh diam, ut efficitur risus molestie eu. Duis et tincidunt nunc, feugiat rhoncus augue. Cras dolor nibh, eleifend et purus sed, fringilla sagittis neque. Nam porta vulputate consequat. Nunc orci quam, rutrum nec dolor et, ultrices pellentesque lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse auctor maximus dui ac molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum scelerisque, augue non interdum egestas, felis eros pharetra ante, quis bibendum nunc odio sed turpis. Proin placerat, arcu vitae ullamcorper hendrerit, magna tortor fringilla justo, at rhoncus libero dolor id tortor. Curabitur quis leo a nisl volutpat sollicitudin sed non velit. Cras est justo, pretium in ex ac, congue tempor mi. Donec est orci, ultrices id ornare at, interdum nec eros. Quisque consectetur, nisl a condimentum efficitur, est nulla accumsan massa, aliquet interdum diam est condimentum nunc. Cras tincidunt purus a nunc porttitor imperdiet. Sed porta nulla at orci sodales, eget posuere nisi auctor. Aenean eu libero varius, condimentum diam sed, suscipit diam. Phasellus venenatis nec ligula non rutrum. Aliquam sit amet dapibus neque. Duis hendrerit malesuada ex eget semper. Quisque malesuada et libero ac mollis.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras a nisi mattis, sollicitudin risus non, pharetra mauris. Morbi eget consectetur neque, eget ornare orci. Cras mi enim, tempor condimentum urna condimentum, maximus semper nisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum gravida nisl non sapien facilisis vestibulum. Morbi luctus vestibulum consectetur. Donec rutrum molestie justo, ut posuere lectus. Vivamus facilisis, elit eget faucibus pharetra, orci dui aliquam neque, eget finibus mauris ante eu odio. Cras blandit urna dolor, ut dictum augue dignissim at. In quis mauris sed lacus venenatis hendrerit gravida id purus. Proin tristique augue id arcu finibus, a cursus neque gravida. Fusce volutpat convallis neque, at laoreet tortor placerat dignissim. Quisque hendrerit maximus arcu, quis vestibulum dui.</p>
<p>Nunc lobortis nibh vel porttitor feugiat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean orci ipsum, auctor elementum tellus at, tincidunt sollicitudin ante. Morbi justo massa, rutrum eu nulla quis, egestas bibendum quam. Aenean pretium, tellus ut porttitor convallis, turpis ligula aliquet lacus, sit amet semper dolor quam nec dui. Quisque quis ornare leo, quis tempor nunc. Nam bibendum in lectus eget pharetra. Vivamus gravida consequat lacinia. Maecenas in magna mollis, consectetur ligula ut, viverra enim. Donec sollicitudin nibh in eros gravida venenatis. Curabitur vehicula ipsum in nulla porttitor molestie. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
<p>In ullamcorper consequat massa, vitae aliquet metus tempus ac. Mauris maximus, sem et lacinia malesuada, lorem dolor molestie sapien, a molestie dolor magna ac lacus. Ut a nibh in tortor condimentum ornare nec at sem. Maecenas iaculis ac ante sit amet efficitur. Ut gravida efficitur accumsan. Donec non metus ut arcu tincidunt blandit nec et urna. Etiam mauris orci, consequat quis ipsum vel, laoreet laoreet orci. Sed felis tortor, elementum id luctus tincidunt, pretium vitae lectus. Ut tincidunt ullamcorper tortor, nec blandit risus eleifend ut. Suspendisse fringilla metus elementum ligula aliquet fermentum non gravida lectus. Vivamus mattis ullamcorper massa ut tristique. Quisque feugiat tristique dictum. Nunc vitae libero massa. Sed sagittis congue euismod.</p>
<p>In sed massa at est malesuada maximus non vel mi. Fusce tincidunt mauris eget metus fringilla venenatis. Ut dapibus nibh diam, ut efficitur risus molestie eu. Duis et tincidunt nunc, feugiat rhoncus augue. Cras dolor nibh, eleifend et purus sed, fringilla sagittis neque. Nam porta vulputate consequat. Nunc orci quam, rutrum nec dolor et, ultrices pellentesque lorem.</p>
```

**Browser support:**

This feature is only fully supported since Chrome 71, Firefox 64 and Opera 54. The other browsers only have a partial support:

> Supports scrollIntoView with boolean parameter, but not `smooth` behavior option

https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview